# Applying theme to site collection and all subsite underneath Issue using Powershell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell, theme

Getting error while applying theme to site collection and all subsite underneath Issue using Powershell in SharePoint 2013

Below is the code

```
$themeName = "PaletteTheme"
$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://SP2013" 
$i=0;
$r =  $SPSite.Url + "/_catalogs/theme/15/PaletteThemeVal.spcolor"


foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs) 
{       
        Write-Host "SP--Web" + $SPWeb.Url
    $colorfile = $SPWeb.GetFile($r)
    Write-Host $colorfile
        $theme=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPTheme]::Open($themeName, $colorfile);
        Write-Host $theme
        Write-Host $theme.Name "to" $SPWeb.Title;         
        $theme.ApplyTo($SPWeb, $false);
}
```

The theme is getting appied to the root site collection but not to the subsites under neath it.
Below is the error i am getting[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below line of code, you are trying to fetch the *colorfile* from the sub web but it's not in the sub web; it's in the root web, that's why it works fine in the root web, but fails in other webs.

```
 $colorfile = $SPWeb.GetFile($r)
```

Try using the below code and logic,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$themeName = "PaletteTheme"
$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://SP2013" 
$r =  $SPSite.Url + "/_catalogs/theme/15/palette005.spcolor"
$rootwebFile = $SPSite.rootweb.GetFile($r)

foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs) 
{       
    Write-Host "SP--Web" + $SPWeb.Url
    Write-Host $colorfile
    $theme=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPTheme]::Open($themeName, $rootwebFile);
    Write-Host $theme
    Write-Host $theme.Name "to" $SPWeb.Title;         
    $theme.ApplyTo($SPWeb, $false);
}

Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```